# Openfire: Add contact subscription status set to 'from' instead of 'both'

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

Hi I'm facing an issue with openfire and smack. I have a jabber bot developed using smack and openfire. 
When any user adds bot has his/her contact, then in the end of whole process, subscription status of ofRoster(openfire) table is set to 'from'. 
The desired result of this process is 'both'.

here is my code of handling new adding connection,

```
xmppConnection.getConnection().getRoster().setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
xmppConnection.getConnection().addPacketListener(
    new PacketListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet paramPacket) {
            System.out.println("\n\n");

            if(paramPacket instanceof Presence){
                Presence presence = (Presence)paramPacket;
                String email = getEmailIdFromJabberId(presence.getFrom());
                System.out.println("chat invite status changed by user: : " + email + " calling listner");
                //if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribed) || presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe) ){
                System.out.println("presence: " + presence.getFrom() + "; type: " + presence.getType() + "; to: " + presence.getTo() + "; " + presence.toXML());
                Roster roster = xmppConnection.getConnection().getRoster();
                for(RosterEntry rosterEntry : roster.getEntries()){
                    System.out.println("jid: " + rosterEntry.getUser() + "; type: " + rosterEntry.getType() + "; status: " + rosterEntry.getStatus());
                }
                System.out.println("\n\n\n");

                if( presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe) ){
                    //chatInviteAcceptanceListner.onChatInviteAccept(email);

                    Presence newp = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                    newp.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                    newp.setPriority(24);
                    newp.setTo(presence.getFrom());
                    //presence.addExtension(new AvatarBroadcastExtension(imageHash));
                    xmppConnection.getConnection().sendPacket(newp);
                } else if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.unsubscribe)){
                    //chatInviteAcceptanceListner.onChatInviteReject(email);
                    Presence newp = new Presence(Presence.Type.unsubscribed);
                    newp.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                    newp.setPriority(24);
                    newp.setTo(presence.getFrom());
                    //presence.addExtension(new AvatarBroadcastExtension(imageHash));
                    xmppConnection.getConnection().sendPacket(newp);
                }
            }


        }
    }, 
    new PacketFilter(){
        public boolean accept(Packet packet) {

            if(packet instanceof Presence){
                Presence presence = (Presence)packet; 
                if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribed) 
                        || presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe)
                        || presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.unsubscribed) 
                        || presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.unsubscribe) ){
                    //System.out.println("packet: " + packet);
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

log of users who is adding the conctact. using pidgin

```
(18:32:22) jabber: jabber_roster_add_buddy(): Adding testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com
(18:32:22) jabber: jabber_roster_update(testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com): [Source: local blist]: groups: Buddies
(18:32:22) jabber: Sending (ssl) (testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin): <iq type='set' id='purple8dde9bec'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'><item jid='testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com' name=''><group>Buddies</group></item></query></iq>
(18:32:22) jabber: Sending (ssl) (testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin): <presence to='testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com' type='subscribe'/>
(18:32:22) jabber: Recv (ssl)(231): <iq type="set" id="88-4977" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com" name="" subscription="none"><group>Buddies</group></item></query></iq>
(18:32:22) jabber: Sending (ssl) (testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin): <iq type='result' id='88-4977'/>
(18:32:22) jabber: Recv (ssl)(89): <iq type="result" id="purple8dde9bec" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin"/>
(18:32:22) jabber: Unhandled IQ with id purple8dde9bec
(18:32:23) jabber: Recv (ssl)(248): <iq type="set" id="963-4978" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com" name="" ask="subscribe" subscription="none"><group>Buddies</group></item></query></iq>
(18:32:23) jabber: Sending (ssl) (testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin): <iq type='result' id='963-4978'/>
(18:32:23) jabber: Recv (ssl)(247): <iq type="set" id="445-4981" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com" name=" Ask a Doctor Now" subscription="to"><group>Buddies</group></item></query></iq>
(18:32:23) jabber: Sending (ssl) (testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin): <iq type='result' id='445-4981'/>
(18:32:23) jabber: Recv (ssl)(164): <presence id="ERM59-6" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com" type="subscribed" from="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com"><priority>24</priority></presence>
(18:32:23) jabber: Recv (ssl)(283): <presence id="ERM59-5" from="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com/smoke" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com/pidgin"><status>141 Doctors Online! Type your question &amp; get an answer now. To find out more, type "Help" and hit ENTER</status><priority>24</priority></presence>
(18:32:23) blist: Updating buddy status for testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com (XMPP)
```

log of bot (smack debug enabled)

sent

```
    <presence id="ERM59-6" to="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com" type="subscribed"><priority>24</priority></presence>
```

received

```
    <presence to="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com" type="subscribe" from="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com"/>
<iq type="set" id="612-4980" to="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com/smoke"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com" subscription="from"/></query></iq>
```

interpreted

```
    <presence to="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com" from="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com" type="subscribe"></presence>
<iq id="612-4980" to="testdoctor@answers.exampledomain.com/smoke" type="set"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="testuser2@answers.exampledomain.com" subscription="from"></item></query></iq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send your own `<presence type="subscribe" to="testusrer@answers.exampledomain.com"/>`, and then that user will need to reply, just as you do, with `<presence type="subscribed"/>`.

[This is described in XMPP6121](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub).

Comment: can we add contact in roster without sending and receiving subscription request in xmpp ? I use github code https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim